# Setting title to displayDialogAsync() dialog box in Microsoft Office Add-In

Tags: office-js, word-addins

In taskpane.js of an Office Add-In, I'm calling displayDialogAsync(), which puts up a dialog box.  The title of the dialog box is (name changed to protect the innocent) "My Word AddIn - [https://myapp.web.core.windows.net/Dialog.html"](https://myapp.web.core.windows.net/Dialog.html%22).  Is there any way to change this title to something more user-friendly and reflective of the product?  I can't seem to find anything in the Microsoft doc.

Comment: It sounds like you are using Microsoft Word. I see that you have the outlook-addin tag. Are you facing this issue in both Outlook and Word?

Comment: I'm only working with Word.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Titlename in header component of the html file.

```
<head>
<title>Titlename</title>
.....
</head>
```